# passing arguments when starting shell script

Tags: bash, scripts

Hi I am trying to make a shell script to accept arguments at startup. The goal I want to achieve is to call a python script which by itself takes arguments.
If the arguments are missing, default statement to make them predefined default values. This is the script I am trying to make work:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script for calling th e python script sniff.py

while getopts d:D o
do case "$o" in
d)  usb_dev="@OPTARG";;
D)  console_outp="@OPTARG";;
*)  usb_dev=ttyUSB1;
    console_outp=INFO;      
esac
done

sniff=/home/user/Documents/Wireshark/Sensniff/sniff.py

sudo python $sniff -d "$usb_dev" -D "$console_outp"
sleep 5d
```

This script of course isn't working. Can you please help me to make this script working?

Comment: You're absolutely right, my answer didn't relate at all; I somehow missed the fact that you were using `getopts`

Comment: Can you point out what's not working exactly? On a side note, I'm sure you can parse the argument within the Python script using some Python function / built-in (if this works for your case).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script for calling th e python script sniff.py

usb_dev=ttyUSB1
console_outp=INFO

while getopts d:D: o
do case "$o" in
d)  usb_dev="$OPTARG";;
D)  console_outp="$OPTARG";;
esac
done

(same as your script)
```

- default value should be initialized before.
- use `$OPTARG` instead of `@OPTARG`
- option are defined as `:D:d:`